# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when switching to Debug

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I get the following error, when I switch the scheme to Debug. In Release I can build without any problems.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTReconnectingWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTPackagerConnection.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTSRWebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libReact.a(RCTInspectorPackagerConnection.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Pod File:

```
target "xy" do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'CxxBridge' # Include if RN >= 0.47
  ]
  pod 'DoubleConversion', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', podspec: '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'


  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
  pod 'react-native-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob'
  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'
  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios'
  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add it to your `pod 'React'` section like this:

```
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTWebSocket'
 ]
```

Don't  forget to run `pod install`.

***If this doesn't work:***

- open XCode,
- click to your Project-Root
- choose your Target
- Tab: Build Phases
- Link Binary with Libraries
- Press the `+` (on the buttom of this Section) and
- add `libRCTWebsocket.a`

This should fix it.